# What matrix operations can be used to parallelize dependency graph processing?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a graph that represents calculation dependencies, and the basic operation I want to perform is an ordered traversal from any node through its dependencies. I have an idea that by representing the graph as an adjacency matrix (probably stored as a sparse matrix) I can potentially use matrix operations to analyze this graph and figure out a more optimal execution plan. E.g. the system could know that the graph has components that are not connected -- they can be evaluated independently -- or it could know that a complex graph can be grouped such that there are a much smaller number of connections between otherwise independent graphs.

Essentially I want to know given a # of CPU's, what's the most efficient allocation of the calculation, where "efficient" here means minimizing inter-communication between the calculators. It feels to me like something where maybe algorithms developed for parallel matrix processing could be useful, but my matrix math knowledge is 25 years old, my graph theory knowledge is weak, and am struggling to form a question to even find papers, resources, algorithms, though I've found some (e.g. http://gauss.cs.ucsb.edu/publication/gapdt-para06.pdf).

E.g. a degenerate / obvious case:

```
A   D
|   |
B   E
|   |
C   F
```

A slightly less obvious case:

```
A   B
 \ /
  C
  |
  D
 / \
E   F
```

DFS evaluation of this starting from A or B yields

```
A>C>D>E>F
B>C>D>E>F
```

That's the "execution plan" you get via a DFS traversal, and you know if you do A first and then B first, everything is consistently evaluated.

By looking at the graph you can see that A and B could be done in parallel but then there's a synchronization where C and D have to be done in serial, and then E and F can be done in parallel. This is a different execution plan.

Which you prefer might even depend on statistics. What if you knew that B was vastly more expensive than A? You might do

```
 A>C>D>E>F
```

while B is running. Or maybe that synchronization is costly. In that case you might prefer A and B in parallel and E & F in serial, because we want to get more work done before we hit the chokepoint at C.

Is there a more general way to do this kind of optimization I should look into?

Comment: In your second example, do you need the result of A and B to compute C? To use a math example, if `C(x) = A(x) + B(x)`, then you obviously cannot compute `C(x)` without first computing `A(x)` and `B(x)`. Is this the case for your situation? It's confusing to me because you also say that "if you knew that B was vastly more expensive than A? You might do `A>C>D>E>F`", but how can you compute C while B is still running?

Comment: C's dependency is that it recomputes by reading latest values of A and B if either A or B changes. There is an edge case where one of A or B has never before evaluated and so you cannot do C(new) = A(new) + B(old). In such a case you might stop evaluation at C, which has the effect of only continuing to C>D>E>F once B is "done" for the first time.

Comment: Why do you care about matrix representation? Imo you first want to determine exactly the analysis you desire. Then if a matrix rep happens to be best/simplest, great, use that. However most graph analysis algorithms don't map nicely into matrix operations, the huge exception being Warshall for transitive closure. Note that minimizing the various costs of parallel computations has a truly enormous research literature. It's unlikely you'll have to invent anything new. Start with a search for "parallel task scheduling".

Comment: I care about it -- or rather, I asked the question :-) -- because of the amount of optimization that's gone into parallel matrix computations. I was looking to see if there was cross-over; if the cross-over is not fruitful then that's fine and I agree with you how the graph gets represented doesn't matter. (Note the paper I cited above is based on this premise: "High–performance graph algorithms from parallel sparse matrices.")

Comment: By the way, I found this which looks interesting -- a different approach to the problem: http://www.chargueraud.org/research/2014/pbfs_pdfs/pbfs_pdfs.pdf